# How do I enable Windows Authentication on a site on a network drive without causing 404 errors in IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-authentication, iis-express

My projects folder is on a network drive, and I'm running Windows 8.1. If I create a brand new web site in Visual Studio 2013 that consists entirely of a single static file, `test.js`, and launch it using the IIS Express 8.5 that came with visual studio, I am able to view the contents of that file in my browser.

But, if I then go into *Web.Config* and turn on Windows Authentication using the code below, that same path now becomes a 404.0 error.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

If, however, I follow this same procedure on a local path, it works just fine. It also works if I open the site in Visual Studio 2010 and run it with the ASP.NET Development Server.

Since it is Windows 8, which prevents other users (and by extension anything running as Administrator) from seeing my network drives, one possibility that occurred to me was that IIS might elevate itself when I turn on Windows Auth, but according to the task manager the IIS worker process is still running as me.

So far, I have tried:

- Switching to a "Classic" app pool so that I can turn on on `<identity impersonate="true"/>`. (had no effect)
- Changing the `physicalPath` of the `<virtualDirectory/>` to the UNC path of the share. (changes the error to 401.3, not authorized)
- Giving Everyone full control of the folder on the file server. (had no effect)
- Changing the default [`<processModel />`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689446%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) so the app pools run as me. (no effect)

One thing that *has* worked is giving "Everyone" access to the share itself, but for obvious security reasons I can't leave it like that. This also only solves the problem with `physicalPath` set to the UNC path (which Visual Studio likes to overwrite).

How can I get Windows Authentication to work on IIS Express without it trying to access my networked files as a different user?

Comment: "Changing the physicalPath of the <virtualDirectory/> to the UNC path of the share. (changes the error to 401.3, not authorized)" is the route you should take further. The application pool must have access to web.config file, or then such issue can happen. Impersonation should be set to false if you don't really need it. You can also set a dedicate account to access the UNC path in virtual directory settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer a member of a domain? Perhaps it's your browser set to autologin using windows credentials for all intranet sites. You can turn this off in Internet explorer and force it to prompt for the user id and password. In internet explorer go to tools, internet options, security, click Local Intranet, then click the Custom Level button at the bottom. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the settings list and change the Logon option from Automatic Logon to Prompt for user name and password. Then it should prompt for login the next time you go, and login using an account you know has access.

Comment: No, I'm not on a domain, but the share is in my "trusted zone", and I'm logging into the site with the same credentials I used to map the share, so I know that account has access to the files.